# Android : Network info measurement

Tags: android, telephony, signal-strength

I am trying to develop android applicaton for getting low-level info about network info measurement.

I want to know How to get these data?

3G:
-RSCP
-ECNO (not Eclo)
-BER

2G:
-RxLevelQuality
-RxLevelSub

Call State:
-Handover
-Dropped Call
-Call Failed

If anyone have idea,Please help me!.

---

[CALL STATE]
I found 'DisconnectCause' from [here](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sipdroid/sipua/phone/Connection.java)
, but I think it always return NORMAL.

Answer (score 2):

You can build your own firmware that collects this information, then deploy this firmware on your personal phone.

Outside of what you get from `TelephonyManager`, the rest of your requested data is inaccessible by Android SDK applications.

> I found 'DisconnectCause' from here , but I think it always return NORMAL.

That is not from the Android OS. That is from SipDroid, a third-party SIP client.

Comment: Even with a custom firmware it might not be possible depending on the hardware of the phone. The baseband part of Android smartphones often simply does not provide that information. It is very, very unlikely that you would be able to develop or compile your own baseband for your phone. If you do please tell me about it and share it. I know only one project implementing a GSM baseband and thats only for the Motorola C123 which is not a smartphone. The projects name is OsmocomBB.